# Setting drop down value in unity with a string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know how to **set**  the dropdownUI value with a string in unity?

I know how to set it up with an int like these

```
public DropDown dropdown;

dropdown.value = 1;
```

However, what I want is to set the value with a given string.

Something like:

```
dropdown.value = "an Option";
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at the documentation of [Dropdown.value](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-value.html):

> `public int value;`
>
> The Value is the index number of the current selection in the Dropdown. 0 is the first option in the Dropdown, 1 is the second, and so on.

it is of type `int` so in short: you can't

---

You could however get the index from the [available options](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-options.html) itself using [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_IndexOf__0_):

```
// returns a list of the text properties of the options
var listAvailableStrings = dropdown.options.Select(option => option.text).ToList();

// returns the index of the given string
dropdown.value = listAvailableStrings.IndexOf("an Option");
```

you could do the same also in one line using [`FindIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_FindIndex_System_Predicate__0__)

```
dropdown.value = dropdown.options.FindIndex(option => option.text == "an Option");
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the version problem or what (I'm currently using `2020.3.6f1 Personal`), everything down below no longer works (Except @Codemaker's answer, which is exactly the same as this one)! Which makes this the "only" viable answer!

Answer (score 4):

We can't add string value to the dropdown value field. So if you need to show an option having the given string then use FindIndex option to find that option in the dropdown and then assign that index to the value field.

```
dropdown.value = dropdown.options.FindIndex(option => option.text == "an Option");
```

Comment: Yes as I already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54021140/7111561) ;)

Answer (score 1):

This answer was written under the assumption you wanted to set the text of a dropdown item. As setting the value as a `string` is impossible, since the value is of type `int`. See derHugo's answer for how you can get the index from an option.

---

`dropdown.value` does not actually represent the text is shows. instead `value`

> is the index number of the current selection in the Dropdown. 0 is the
>   first option in the Dropdown, 1 is the second, and so on.

As described in the [docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-value.html)

What you are looking for is `Dropdown.itemText` ([docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-itemText.html))

Meaning to set the text in your dropdown item you'll have to do the following: `dropdown.itemText = "an Option";`

A more complete guide on how dropdown menu's work can be found in the [Unity manual here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Dropdown.html)

Comment: You where a bit faster so here you go: you could use `dropdown.value = dropdown.options.IndexOf("an Option")`

Comment: It looks like i misinterpreted the question, I think what you just said IS actually what the OP is looking for. You should probably turn that into an answer as it appears to be more correct @derHugo

Comment: `itemText` is a `Text`, so you have to set the value by `dropdown.itemText.text = "an Option";`